# Bound different events to different ids in a single statemenet

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have different events for different ids grouping them together

e.g

```
//non working code
    $("#a").change,$("b").click (function()  
    { 
    //my code here
    });
```

I would like #a to have only a change event and #b only a click event.
(I can always multiselect use on and get the events and id and filter accordingly but I am wondering if it can be done so that specific events are explicitly added on specific ids (not both) in a single statement.

Comment: Multi selector http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Check [Bacon.js](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js): merging of event streams is one of its finest features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

write it as a separate handler method and then refer the method as the handler for each of the events

```
function handler(){
    //my code here
}
$("#a").change(handler)
$("b").click(handler)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I was just wondering if I can combine them both somehow without using a different function, however in terms of attaching different events to the different ids without on (in which case both will be bound to the events) your answer is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#a, #b').on('change click', function(){});
```

2 parter...seperate your selectors by a comma and using the on function, plug your separate events in the first parameter separated by a space, followed by your handler function

Comment: This will bind both events to both elements.  Not sure if that's what he wants.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The problem with this is that both a and b will have change and click attached, I would like a to have only a change event and b only click event if possible straight away (I can always get the events and id and filter accordingly but I am wondering if it can be done otherwise)

Comment: oh good call! then it'd be much easier to have separate listener lines going to a separate handler function